# Pass data between independent components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner in Angular 2 and now developing small SPA. In component Login I receive some data via http service, set data into class User and need that data to be available in some other components. The problem is that components are completely independent (don't have parent-child relation). Are there any mechanisms in Angular 2 to pass data in that way?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Yeah, I have read that. But the first component doesn't include the second component in the template. Second component loads using this.router.navigate(['/main'])

Comment: Look at Parent and children communicate via a service part of the link @JBNizet gave. The Subject usage is all you will need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I would like to recommends you to use Service to pass data between components.

Here are some example how components can communicate using 3 different. ways,

[Angular2-playground Demo](http://rawgit.com/SekibOmazic/angular2-playground/master/dist/index.html) its code [available on Github](https://github.com/SekibOmazic/angular2-playground)

Suppose if you are creating service **S1** and providing that service in `app.module.ts` file it will create a *Singleton instance of that service*. If you make changes in service from **Component 1**, than you will can get that modified data in **Component 2**.

Or you can do like that add service in separate module for separate functionality, so that service can be accessible in that module only.

> Summary: you can use services to passing data between components, it will very helpful.