# render html after completion process of component in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am calling a api in my app component after getting the response I can decide which div is to show and which div is to hide. 
But it render the html before completion of component process.
Below are the code example.

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers, RequestOptions, Response, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private static isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  private userData: any;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  public isLoggedIn() {
    return UserService.isUserLoggedIn;
  }

  public getUserData() {
    return this.userData;
  }

  setUserData() {

    var url = 'http://api.example.in/user/logincheck';
    this.http
      .get(url)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.userData = data;
        if (typeof this.userData.id != 'undefined' && this.userData.id > 0) {
          UserService.isUserLoggedIn = true;
        }
      },
      (err) => { throw err; }
      );
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './services/user/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.userLoggedInCheck();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  userLoggedInCheck() {
    this.userService.setUserData();
  }
}
```

I want here to load html after complete of userLoggedInCheck function called.

Answer (score 0):

return a true value from **userLoggedInCheck** if the necessary conditions are met and assign it to a variable in the  app.component.ts file. In the html file place the content within an *ngIf based on the return variable from the function.

for eg.

```
 userLoggedInCheck() {
    this.showHtml = this.userService.setUserData();
  }
```

and in html

```
<div *ngIf="showHtml"> 
   ....... // code
</div>
```

Comment: I have made a service so I want to send a request only 1 time when page load only. My html part is in header component if I put api call in header component it calls every time when other routing clicked.

Comment: try using the service file as a shared one ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527284/pass-data-between-independent-components-in-angular-2 )  and then control the html using *ngIf.